# Change selection in ComboBox automatically

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two combo boxes. How to make selection in one ComboBox change automatically when user changes the item selection in another combobox? I assume something like this:

```
 private void ComboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
      ComboBox2_SelectionChanged();
}
```

but what to pass as an argument?

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19829381/is-it-possible-to-fire-combobox-selectedindex-changed-event-even-when-old-and-ne. It will help you. Thanks

Comment: Why you are not using SelectedIndexChanged event and in this event change the item selecteD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not very specific, so here is another way to do this, based on what you are trying to achieve:

```
private void ComboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgse)
{
      ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = (sender as ComboBox).SelectedIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is customary to data bind an object to the `ComboBox.SelectedItem` property so that we know which item has been selected in the UI. In these cases, it is very easy to act upon a selected value... take this example:

```
public SomeDataType SelectedItem
{
    get { return selectedItem; }
    set
    {
        selectedItem = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
        DoSomethingWithSelectedValue(SelectedItem);
    }
}
```

Now, each time a selection is made in the `ComboBox`, this `DoSomethingWithSelectedValue` method will be called and you can do whatever you like in there... it could be setting a new `ComboBox.ItemsSource` dependent on the selected value from the first `ComboBox`, or it could be just setting the `ComboBox.SelectedItem`... whatever you need.

Comment: With C# 6.0 `nameof(SelectedItem)` this is really the only proper solution in wpf.

Comment: Hi @Sinatr... I certainly prefer this method (perhaps because I use MVVM?), but I know that some people hate the idea of a property doing anything that doesn't relate to that property. Still, each to their own.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it from the model like this:

```
// View

<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding First}" ItemsSource="{Binding Selectables}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Second}" ItemsSource="{Binding Selectables2}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Grid.Column="1" />

// Model

public ObservableCollection<string> Selectables { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<string> Selectables2 { get; set; }
private string _first;
private string _second;
public string First {
    get {
        return _first;
    }
    set {
        if(_first == value) {
            return;
        }
        _first = value;
        Second = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("First");
    }
}

public string Second {
    get {
        return _second;
    }
    set {
        if(_second == value) {
            return;
        }
        _second = value;
        First = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Second");
    }
}
```

Interestingly that also works:

```
// View

<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding First}" ItemsSource="{Binding Selectables}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Second}" ItemsSource="{Binding Selectables}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Grid.Column="1" />

// Model

public ObservableCollection<string> Selectables { get; set; }
private string _first;
private string _second;
public string First {
    get {
        return _first;
    }
    set {
        _first = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("First");
    }
}

public string Second {
    get {
        return _second;
    }
    set {
        _second = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Second");
    }
}
```

Tho First and Second should be different, but somehow `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` connected them if the two `ItemsSource` is the same.